# Multiple ajax calls for included js files inside jsp fragment

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am including a jsp fragment by making an ajax call. Now this jsp frag happened to include several js files.

When the ajax request is completed, it is loading each of the included js files (on fragments) using a separate get request. (I checked this using firebug.)

Now is this the correct behavior (making separate get calls) or am I missing something.

Is there a way to include the js files and send the response in one go ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get with in a single request, is to merge them into a single file.